# Carification on the VLD

Tags: dll, memory-leaks

ALL,

I have an application which loads multiple DLLs. One of those DLLs has a memory leak.

From what I understand the best tool to find memory leaks is VLD ;-)
So I downloaded the latest release and installed it in the default location.

Now the documentation says that I need to include the vld.h file somewhere once and link to the VLD libraries and then just run the application.

My question is - should I include it in the DLL code where the leak occurs or I do that in the main application? And the same with the linking...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `vld.h` to each source file (if you use precompiled headers, you can include `vld.h` once to the header) of each DLL, or some specific DLL. Then rebuild them / it.

`vld.h` redefines allocation functions, so when a source file is compiled, all allocation functions become special functions from VLD. Thus VLD can save information about allocations and deallocations.

You can use VLD in your main application. But in this case, you will get information about allocations made by your main application code only.